# Dual-booting Kali Linux and Windows 7, error with file: "\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr"

Tags: windows, partitioning, grub2, kali-linux

I have tried to install Kali Linux 1.0.6 alongside my current OS - Windows 7 64 bit. I have a Dell computer, with SSD hard drive only (256 GB).
At first I tried installing Kali a few times and made a few mistakes, and I'm afraid I made some damage that prevents it from installing properly now.

**Described here are the first few attempts:**

First I cleared 25 free GB for the kali partitions. 
I tried to do it without reading through long tutorials, downloaded the iso file "kali-linux-1.0.6-amd64" and burned it on DVD, went through the installation and choose "Guided – use the largest continuous free space" option in the "Partition disks" step. 
On the step "install the grub boot loader on a hard disk" the Kali installation didn't recognized my Windows 7 but I told it not to install GRUB in the MBR, but on a random partition. I choose: "/dev/sda5". When configuring the package manager I agreed to use a network mirror. The installation failed in the middle, and I exited though a message said the system may be left in an unstable state.

Everything worked perfectly on Window 7 and I tried again. I deleted the newly created partitions, did it all the same but this time it worked (can't figure out any change I made). I still chose the partition for the GRUB absolutely randomly, and when the installation ended I used EasyBCD 2.2 to be able to load kali, chose "GRUB 2" with the option "Automatically locate and load". Then when I rebooted and chose "kali linux" OS, I got a message that "windows failed to start." and that: 
"File: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
Status: 0xc000007b
Info: Application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors"
I tried again on EasyBCD with all possible drives for the kali entry, and nothing worked.

Again I deleted the newly created partitions, and I realized that the whole part of choosing the partition for the GRUB is probably important (yes, I'm not very good at installing stuff...), I read about it and then chose the partition called "bios-grub" (or maybe a name similar to this). Still I got the same problem with "windows failed to start" when the installation ended and I tried to boot to Kali.

**Last attempt here:**

Not giving up yet, I followed this tutorial and did the whole partitioning step manual: 
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/24/dual-boot-windows-7-and-kali-linux/
I don't know exactly what it means, but it didn't show me the choice primary/logical (maybe it's related to the fact I have SSD). Anyway, I'm getting the exact same "window failed to start" message again even when I understand and carefully chose all partitions and definitions manually. I check and I do have a 9 KB file in "C:\NST" called "AutoNeoGrub0.mbr".

**What should I do? I really need this Kali OS very soon.**

**attachments:**

If it helps, here's what I currently this in the EasyBCD overview:

```
There are a total of 6 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 7
Timeout: 5 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Network
BCD ID: {bb2f9fc0-147d-11e3-9630-74867a357b03}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #2
Name: Hard Drive
BCD ID: {bd7b819a-2b07-11e3-be6e-806e6f6e6963}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #3
Name: CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
BCD ID: {74674154-1466-11e3-8a62-74867a357b03}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #4
Name: EFI USB Device
BCD ID: {bb2f9fbc-147d-11e3-9630-74867a357b03}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #5
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.efi

Entry #6
Name: Kali Linux
BCD ID: {bb2f9fd7-147d-11e3-9630-74867a357b03}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
```

Answer (score 1):

You have Windows 7 UEFI installation (and GPT formated disk).

EasyBCD 2.2 cannot create UEFI boot entries.

Install every OS using UEFI boot for installation media (USB/DVD).

Select which OS to boot using firmware boot device selection key.

Comment: I'm sorry for me ignorance, but your answer was not clear to me. can you please explain me what is UEFI installation and GPT formated disk?

and just to make sure - do you suggest I re-install both windows and kali-linux with this UEFI?

Comment: Windows 7 is installed already using UEFI firmware settings. Just boot Kali source the UEFI way and reinstall.